# Which X-15 and SpaceShipOne flights took Coriolis forces into account on their flight path?

Tags: rotation, sub-orbital, spaceplane, x-15

I wonder whether those X-15 and SpaceShipOne flights that reached space took into account the rotational Coriolis forces, so that they wouldn't reenter above a location where it would be too far from their spaceport to go to. Where the rotational forces during their flights enough so that they had to be taken into account? Around 50 mi (80 km) altitude there are half aerodynamic lift and half rotational force acting on a spaceplane, above that altitude the centripetal force is stronger. These are very approximate values of course, and I'd like to know for which flights the rotation force was being taken into account.

Comment: The X-15 never flew in a horizontal direction at high speed and great heights. It flew a very steep parabola, not covering large amounts of distance on the ground.

Comment: @asdfex But what about those two flights that went above 100 km? If they flew such steep parabola they anyway must have flown horizontally relative to the surface due to rotation. I wonder how large the difference was.

Comment: The difference was tiny. There was no flight that stayed above 80km for 2-3 minutes.

Comment: @asdfex can you source that, please?

Comment: X-15 never got anywhere close to orbital speed. Karman line type calcs don't apply. Your line about "around 50 mi" is not correct, it's not the altitude that matters.

Comment: The whole flight above ~50km was an unpowered, ballistic trajectory. That's about 140s above 80km (with a peak at 105km).

Comment: @OrganicMarble What does orbital speed have to do with my question? And about 50 mi _is_ correct, just very imprecise.

Comment: Q: what goes into the equation for centripetal force? You're mixing up the definition of the Karman line with that comment about 'around 50 mi'. It only applies to things that go fast. Consider an idealized sounding rocket on a vertical trajectory that peaks at 50 mi. What's the centripetal force?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I mean the rotation of a planet beneath the spaceplane.

Comment: Ah, in that case you man Coriolis force, not centripetal

Comment: @JCRM I think so.